# Can we call or combine Select and a procedure in Spring data jpa @Query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a procedure written in database. my_procedure(val1, val2)

So, lets say I have a database query like this:

```
select field1 as fieldName,  field2 as fieldId
(select * from mydb.my_procedure(id)) as aValue // A procedure call
from mydb.my_table
```

I want to convert this to Spring's Data JPA @Query. Something like this:

```
@Query (" HERE I WANT THE ABOVE QUERY TO IMPLEMENT")
public List<MyTable> getDetails ()
```

Are we allowed to do this?

**UPDATE**

For example I have below query which I want to convert.

```
select id, name, roll,
(select * from db.calculate_fee (date, id)) fee
from Student
where  id = 1 AND roll = 5
```

I want to do something like

```
@Query("SELECT student, (select * from db.calculate_fee (date, id) fee FROM Student student "
            + "WHERE student.id=:id, "
            + "AND student.name=:roll")
    public List<Student> getDetails(@Param("id") Integer id, @Param("roll") Integer roll);
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with a native query?

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select field1 as fieldName, field2 as fieldId...")
List<MyTable> getDetails();
```

*(by the way, public is not needed for 'getDetails' as Repositories are interfaces)*

Answer (score 0):

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "getAllEmployees",
                                    procedureName = "get_all_employees",
        resultClasses = Employees.class)
})
```

```
@Procedure(name = "getAllEmployees")
List<Employees> getAllEmployees();
```

[Complete tutorial](https://medium.com/@senanayake.kalpa/calling-stored-procedure-using-spring-jpa-ee37fa58ca2d)